# How to forcefully (cheat) change a readonly cvar on doom3?

Tags: cheats, doom-3

I am trying to modify this cvar: g_armorprotection; it becomes readonly just after loading a game.

**Why?**

I am playing doom3 + evolution mod, with engineer class (weaker), and in nightmare mode (max hp is 25).

I got plenty armor but it is almost not used, it absorbs too little damage, so basically it is one-hit kill on my char...

I can build armor from bio-energy but I almost do not have a chance to do that as my char quickly dies having to reload, but then I already know what to do and almost not get hit...

I don't intend to replay, so it is somewhat annoying the way it is now because my char "always" don't get hit (because I reload and already know what to do).

**Is there some way or tool to do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking to the mod author and reading the mod code, I found that g_armorprotection cvar gets reset everytime so it is not readonly!
There is "nothing" that can be done.